# Prevent duplicate api submission ASP.NET Core Web API using lock

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to block the duplicate the request from client on back-end side.
(This question is about ignoring client-side support actions such as: disabling buttons, displaying loading screen, Google re-captcha, ...)

Here is my idea:

- Declare a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>` as a singleton.
- Create one api [GET] `api/survey/token` to generate an unique token on back-end site and return to client.
- Save the newly generated unique token to the `ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>`.

**When user submits information**

- Create api [POST] `api/survey` to submit survey information (name, description and **unique token**)
- Check whether **unique token** is in dictionary or not.

  - If token is in dictionary:

    - Remove token from dictionary.
    - Save the information into database.
  - If token is not in dictionary.

    - Return error response to client.

**Here is my implementation:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SurveyController : ControllerBase
    {
        #region Properties

        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime> _concurrentDictionary;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public SurveyController(ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime> concurrentDictionary)
        {
            _concurrentDictionary = concurrentDictionary;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        ///     Generate token asynchronously.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet("token")]
        public virtual IActionResult GetSubmissionTokenAsync()
        {
            var uniqueToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
            var generateUniqueTokenModel = new GenerateSurveyTokenResultViewModel();
            generateUniqueTokenModel.UniqueToken = uniqueToken;

            var dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

            _concurrentDictionary.TryAdd(uniqueToken, dateTime);

            return Ok(generateUniqueTokenModel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add survey asynchronously.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost("")]
        public virtual async Task<IActionResult> AddSurveyAsync([FromBody] AddSurveyViewModel model)
        {
            // Validate model.
            if (model == null)
            {
                model = new AddSurveyViewModel();
                TryValidateModel(model);
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var apiMessage = new ApiMessageViewModel();

            lock (_concurrentDictionary)
            {
                // Check whether token is registered before or not.
                if (!_concurrentDictionary.TryGetValue(model.UniqueToken, out var dateTime))
                {
                    apiMessage.Message = "INVALID_SUBMISSION_TOKEN";
                    return NotFound(apiMessage);
                }

                // Remove the registered unique token.
                _concurrentDictionary.TryRemove(model.UniqueToken, out var expiredTime);
            }

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            });

            return Ok();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

In my implementation, I lock the **ConcurrentDictionary** when I want to add the unique token to dictionary, and also lock the **ConcurrentDictionary** when I remove the unique token.

My question is:

- Should the lock affects the system performance when thousands of requests come to my api server ?
- Are there any better ways to archieve the goal that prevent duplicate form submission ?

**** UPDATE *****

I have implemented an attribute named **RequestCacheAttribute**

```
public class RequestCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        #region Properties

        //private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime> _concurrentDictionary;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var availableTokens = (ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime>)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime>));
            var eTag = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.ETag];
            Debug.WriteLine($"ETag = {eTag}");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eTag))
            {
                context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
                return;
            }

            lock (availableTokens)
            {
                if (!availableTokens.TryGetValue(eTag, out var dateTime))
                {
                    context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
                    return;
                }

                availableTokens.TryRemove(eTag, out var date);
            }


            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
```

In this attribute, before going to API [POST]`api/survey` to create survey information, I lock the `ConcurrentDictionary` , check whether **unique token** is available or not. If its available, allow user to enters the API and remove the unique token from `ConcurrentDictionary`, otherwise, prevent user from accessing the API.

Is it bad for the performance ?

Thank you,

Comment: Locking is not necessary when using ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: A memory based lock will work only in a single server scenario. Sooner or later you'll upgrade to a multiserver farm and suddenly realize this doesn't work. Instead, move duplication prevention to a lower layer, e.g. have a unique database constraint or have a messaging middleware with a single queue that easily catches duplicates coming one after the other.

Comment: Without lock, when I submit multiple requests (using client tool), some concurrent requests still submit information to api successfully. That means information will be duplicated in SQL Server.

Due to the business, none of information in my survey form is a primary key,.